# How to change the color of the option menu

Tags: android, android-xml, android-styles

this is my style.xml

Now when i click the option menu. the text color appears to be black. i need to change it to white

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/redDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/redLite</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/redDark</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/redDark</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>
```

Comment: It works for options of menu with the attribute "showAsAction = Always" but it doesn't work in the "popupmenu"

Answer (score 0):

You can change menu items text color programmatically.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity, menu);
        for(int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
            MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
            SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(menu.getItem(i).getTitle().toString());
            spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, spanString.length(), 0); //fix the color to white
            item.setTitle(spanString);
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: while it get applied to option menu too.. i need to change the color of option menu @Bhuvanesh Bs

Comment: can't understand. if you asking about the background color you can change that too.. see updated answer.

Comment: i was asking about the option menu that comes when clicking the option button(left side betton near the home button) @Bhuvanesh Bs

Comment: can you please explain this line  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity, menu); what is menu the second parameter here

Comment: are you using Activity or fragment?

Comment: activity @Bhuvanesh Bs

Comment: menu is the parameter we got from `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) `: 
 The Menu to inflate into. The items and submenus will be added to this Menu.

Comment: still it appears in black

Comment: which color you used here `new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN)`

Comment: new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE)

Comment: if you are using onpreper action menu method remove that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154437/discussion-between-martin-j-and-bhuvanesh-bs).

Comment: can u pls check the chat

Answer (score 0):

Check if this works

```
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/myMenuTextApearance</item>
```

and add this text style in the styles

```
<style name="myMenuTextApearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_dark</item>
</style>
```